# bs4 import error using pipenv

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pipenv

having a little trouble trying to use pipenv.
i ran the following command

pipenv install bs4

and it came out with :

```
���������������������������������Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in /home/sam/.local/share/virtualenvs/ICOtools-kKWO0fqD/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in /home/sam/.local/share/virtualenvs/ICOtools-kKWO0fqD/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from bs4)

Adding bs4 to Pipfile's [packages]���
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies���
Locking [packages] dependencies���
Updated Pipfile.lock (5de6ca)!
```

then when i run my script i still get

```
'ImportError: No module named bs4'
```

the second line of my script is

```
'from bs4 import BeautifulSoup'
```

I am running Ubuntu(xenial) on a chromebook using crouton not sure if that effects this.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you did not activate your virtual env. By default when you run `pipenv install bs4` a virtualenv is created. You can run `pipenv shell` from same directory to activate it(and `exit` to deactivate).
EX:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-zesty:~$ pipenv install bs4
Installing bs4…
Collecting bs4
Collecting beautifulsoup4 (from bs4)
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py2-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: beautifulsoup4, bs4
Successfully installed beautifulsoup4-4.6.0 bs4-0.0.1

Adding bs4 to Pipfile's [packages]…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Updated Pipfile.lock (9e60b9)!
ubuntu@ubuntu-zesty:~$ pipenv shell
Spawning environment shell (/bin/bash). Use 'exit' to leave.
ubuntu@ubuntu-zesty:~$ source /home/ubuntu/.local/share/virtualenvs/ubuntu-7Wf190Ea/bin/activate
(ubuntu-7Wf190Ea) ubuntu@ubuntu-zesty:~$ python
Python 2.7.14 (default, Sep 23 2017, 22:06:14)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bs4
>>> print (bs4.__version__)
4.6.0
>>> quit()
(ubuntu-7Wf190Ea) ubuntu@ubuntu-zesty:~$ exit
exit
ubuntu@ubuntu-zesty:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of pipenv install bs4

try `pipenv install beautifulsoup4`

Comment: Exact same result :(

Comment: @SamParker try 'from bs4 import BeautifulSoup4'